# How to transform JSON SList to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipython

```
a = ['{"type": "book",', 
     '"title": "sometitle",', 
     '"author": [{"name": "somename"}],', 
     '"year": "2000",', 
     '"identifier": [{"type": "ISBN", "id": "1234567890"}],', 
     '"publisher": "somepublisher"}', '',
     '{"type": "book",', '
     '"title": "sometitle2",', 
     '"author": [{"name": "somename2"}],', 
     '"year": "2001",', 
     '"identifier": [{"type": "ISBN", "id": "1234567890"}],', 
     '"publisher": "somepublisher"}', '']
```

I have this convoluted SList and I would like to ultimately get it into a tidy pandas dataframe.

I have tried a number of things, for example:

```
i = iter(a)
b = dict(zip(i, i))
```

Unfortunately, this creates a dictionary that looks even worse:

```
{'{"type": "book",':
...
```

Where I had an SList of dictionaries, I now have a dictionary of dictionaries.

I also tried

```
pd.json_normalize(a)
```

but this throws an error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`

I also tried

```
r = json.dumps(a.l)
loaded_r = json.loads(r)
print(loaded_r)
```

but this yields a list

```
['{"type": "book",',
...
```

Again, in the end I'd like to have a pandas dataframe like this

```
type   title       author     year ...

book   sometitle   somename   2000 ...
book   sometitle2 somename2   2001
```

Obviously, I haven't really gotten to the point where I can feed the data to a pandas function. Everytime I did that, the functions screamed at me...

Comment: your data does not look properly formatted

Comment: Yes, I believe that's a central part of my problem. This is how I receive it from somebody else's script.

Comment: when I copied your data, it returned errors, possibly because of the single quotes on each line. Could you test that the sample data you shared works, because it returns errors on my end

Comment: I've changed it to be an MWE. Now there are several rows missing but there are two full observations.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['{"type": "book",', 
     '"title": "sometitle",', 
     '"author": [{"name": "somename"}],', 
     '"year": "2000",', 
     '"identifier": [{"type": "ISBN", "id": "1234567890"}],', 
     '"publisher": "somepublisher"}', '',
     '{"type": "book",', 
     '"title": "sometitle2",', 
     '"author": [{"name": "somename2"}],', 
     '"year": "2001",', 
     '"identifier": [{"type": "ISBN", "id": "1234567890"}],', 
     '"publisher": "somepublisher"}', '']

b = "[%s]" % ''.join([',' if i == '' else i for i in a ]).strip(',')
data = json.loads(b)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   type       title                   author  year  \
0  book   sometitle   [{'name': 'somename'}]  2000   
1  book  sometitle2  [{'name': 'somename2'}]  2001   

                               identifier      publisher  
0  [{'type': 'ISBN', 'id': '1234567890'}]  somepublisher  
1  [{'type': 'ISBN', 'id': '1234567890'}]  somepublisher
```

Comment: maybe it just suits your sample data.